# How to push unique array into array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to get comment likes by comment_id from comment_likes table and sending all data into same array but comment_like array repeating same value many times below is my codes

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
$stmt->execute(array($findCommentById));
$comments_list = array();
while($rows = $stmt->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['comment_id'] = $rows['comment_id']; 
    $temp['user_name'] = $rows['user_name'];
    
    $selectLikedCommentUser = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM commentLikes WHERE comment_id = ?");
    $selectLikedCommentUser->execute(array($rows['comment_id']));
    while($commentLikesRows = $selectLikedCommentUser->fetch()){
        $LikesCommentUserId[] = array("LikesCommentUserId"=>$commentLikesRows['user_id']);
    }
    
    $temp['CommentLikesByUser'] = $LikesCommentUserId;
    // its repeating data too many times.
    
    array_push($comments_list, $temp);
}
echo json_encode(array("commentList"=>$comments_list));
```

$comments_list not showing correct data its looping $LikesCommentUserId array many time in same index please help me to get exact data.

Comment: Have you looked at doing a JOIN in SQL?

Comment: No i don't know how to use join

Comment: i want to get comment likes in same comment index

Comment: sorry i mean to say i don't have any idea to use join in this example

Comment: I want to show logged in user his already liked a post if logged user and comment user id matched